# Set of standard accessibility guidelines for online maps?

Tags: web-mapping, tools, accessibility

Recently I've been designing maps without navigation tools like the Zoom In/Out and Pan tools, or arrows to pan north, pan west, etc.

Instead, most modern mapping APIs support the direct use of the map itself to handle navigation - drag the map to pan, double-click to zoom in, scroll the mouse wheel, shift-drag to zoom, etc.

**Is there a set of standard accessibility guidelines for online maps?**

Are there valid reasons for needing a "click to pan" control, or any of the other old-school navigation controls? For example, are they used by screen readers or other accessibility aids?

I note that Google Maps has a Pan control, even though it's not strictly necessary.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C Research and Development Working Group discusses detailed guidlines in https://www.w3.org/WAI/RD/wiki/Accessible_Maps

Comment: Also note that the RD WG has transitioned to become the Accessible Platform Architectures Working Group (APA WG)  per the [mailing list archives](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-wai-rd/2015Jul/0011.html). Their new work can be found at https://github.com/w3c/apa and https://www.w3.org/WAI/APA/.

Answer (score 3):

The W3C standard that is most relevant is [WCAG 2.0 AA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag).  Essentially, it's a matter of evaluating if something is Perceivable, Operable, Understandable & Robust.

I really don't know how you'd be able to navigate a map without a keyboard (and there are a lot of users who don't use mice).  You could possibly make the navigation appear when the focus is on the map.  However, you'd also want to make sure that the map is operational.

I haven't heard of a common set of standards for map accessibility. I think right now the expectations are pretty low.

Screen reader users are one important case, but I think in the mapping world many people start there, decide it can't be done and move on.  There are people with low vision, colour blindness, mobility chalenges, etc.

There is an interesting list in [OpenStreet Map's Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Accessibility).

Answer (score 1):

Something to be mindful of is who the targeted audience is.  Some users may not understand the map to pan control, whereas others may.  The Flex API widgets/fonts are small and are not very easy to enlarge with a web browser.  Here is an interesting article.

[Trends in Web Mapping: It’s all about usability](http://www.directionsmag.com/articles/trends-in-web-mapping-its-all-about-usability/123318)